# How can I show model data's contents in html file?

Tags: python, html, django

I wrote in results.html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Score</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Score</h1>
    <h2>Your score is {{ scoreresults.result }}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

But now, this part `{{ user.result }}` of `<h2>Your score is {{ user.result }}
</h2>` is blank in my browser.

I wrote in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class ImageAndUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", verbose_name="imageforegin")
    result = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.user,self.id)
```

So,ImageAndUser model has result data.
I cannot understand how to designate ImageAndUser model in results.html.
Furthermore,
I wrote in serializer.py

```
from .forms import UserImageForm
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ImageAndUser

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields =(
            'image',
            'result',
            'user',
            'id',
        )

        read_only_fields = (
            'user',
        )

    def create(self, attrs):
        attrs['user'] = self.context.get('request').user
        print(attrs)
        return super(ImageSerializer,self).create(attrs)
```

Now,I wrote in views.py

```
def scoreresults(request):
    d = {
        'scoreresults': ImageAndUser.objects.result(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/results.html', d)
```

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^scoreresults$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/accounts/results.html'),
        name='tcresults'),
]
```

But it did not work.

So,how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: I did not write anything  which relate with results.html in views.py

Comment: So, when and how does your html template get used?

Comment: Oh,really?So,what should I write in my views.py?

Comment: What is the `.tc()` method? And why have you posted a view that renders a completely different template? And what does the serializer have to do with anything? And what do your urls look like? And which URL are you actually going to?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thx. .tc() is wrong and renders template is also wrong, sorry.I wanna show my model's data, it is my only goal.I think serializer is related with my goal, but it is wrong maybe.URL is accounts/socreresults.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of bits here but none of them are linked up to one another.

The main problem is your url; it does not point to your view. Instead of using a TemplateView declared in the url itself, you should point it to the view function you have defined:

```
url(r'^scoreresults$', views.scoreresults, name='tcresults')
```

You don't seem to be using the serializer at all; and you don't need it.

Comment: thx, ur comment.I wrote ur code,but it did not work.what should i do?